# Hebrew letters differentiate between final and non final forms

Tags: hebrew

I had installed `cjhebrew` package on Mac OS and TeXShop. Hebrew letters.
Issue:
I had a hard time to differentiate:

The small k is suppose to typset a Kaf symbol while K supposed to typset a Kaf final form
Any suggestions are welcome

```
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
1.      Aleph       &\hspace {0.5 cm}       & \cjRL{'}  \\    %
2. Bet          &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{ b}  \\
3.          Gimmel  &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{ g}  \\
4.           Dalet  &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{d}   \\
5.      Hey     &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{h}  \\
6.      Vav     &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{w}   \\
7.      Zayin   &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{z}    \\ 
8.      Chet        &\hspace{ 0.5 cm}       &\cjRL{.h}  \\ 
9.          Tet     &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{.t} \\
 10.        Yod     &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{ y} \\   
11.         Caph    &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{k}   \\   % change to small k not final 17/jul 
12.         Lamed   &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{l}  \\
13.     Mem     &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{m} \\
14.     Nun     &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{N}\\
15.     Samek   &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{s}   \\
16.     Ayin        &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{.s} \\
17.     Pey     &\hspace{0.5cm}     &\cjRL{pf}\\
18.     Tzadi   &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{.S}  \\
19.     Qopf        &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{q} \\
20.     Resh        &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{r}   \\
21.     Shin        &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{,s}   \\
22.     Tav     &\hspace{0.5 cm}        &\cjRL{ t} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please post a full example, clearly showing the issue you are having. It can probably be shown outside of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Both `k` and `K` work for me, both inside a `tabular` and outside.

Comment: The example is as shown all 22 letters..as above

Comment: 11.   Caph non final form &\hspace{0.5 cm} &\cjRL{k} \\       %  problem
11a.          Caph final form          &\hspace{0.5 cm}   &\cjRL{K} \\.     % problem

Comment: Please post code that can compile and shows the error. Final and non-final forms work for me, but I cannot guess what other code/package(s) you are using.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\centering
\begin{tabular} { l l l }

11.   Caph  &\hspace{0.5 cm} &\cjRL{k} \\ 
11a.          Caph final form    &\hspace{0.5 cm}   &\cjRL{K}\\
13.  Mem form &\hspace{0.5 cm}  &\cjRL{m} \\  
13a.          Mem final form &\hspace{0.5cm}  &\cjRL{M} \\         
14.  Nun  &\hspace{0.5 cm}  &\cjRL{N}\\ 
14a.         Nun.     final form &\hspace{0.5cm}  &\cjRL{n} \\ 
18.  Tzadi final form &\hspace{0.5 cm}  &\cjRL{.S} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Comment: tabular or not tabular it makes no diffence. Issue is: cjRL {k} Is same as \cjRL{K}.

Comment: Found it: use `\cjRL{k|}`

Comment: Solution is to use \cjRL{k/zeronojoin}.    This is for non final form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `texdoc cjhebrew` for the manual.

Use `K` if you want the final form to appear in the middle of a word.
Two other methods, `k!` and `k\endofword`  will also produce the final form where it is not automatically produced.

And there are two methods to produce the non-final form where otherwise the final form will be auto-produced.

[image: final k]

"Normally the final letters are used automatically; <mlk> will become
!Klm. Sometimes it is necessary to use final letters in places where they will not
be set automatically, e. g. in the middle of a word. To do this you either use
the coding according to table 1 or you put an exclamation mark (!) after the consonant; alternatively you can use the \endofword command. For example, a
final mem could be achieved by typing <M>, <m!> or <m\endofword>.
On the other hand, sometimes you will not want this automatic replacement.
In these cases you put | after the consonant or use the \zeronojoin com- |
mand. Both <m|> and <m\zeronojoin> will give you a normal mem."

MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\<mkl> normal

\<mlk> auto final

\<mKl> final form K in middle of word

\<mk!l> final form k! in middle of word

\<mk\endofword l> final form k\textbackslash endofword in middle of word

\<mlk|> auto final suppressed with k|

\<mlk\zeronojoin> auto final suppressed with k\textbackslash zeronojoin 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works on my Mac OS TExShop. I am wondering why you dont use the \cjRL{k} command

Comment: Can I print k alone as a non final form ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Note: This is correct. The Hebrew Ayin is fixed here.